# Microsoft Azure Bing News Search API bug with query parameter "2018-08-14..2018-09-15" for freshness

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

When I used the Bing News Search API service:

https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news/search

... with query parameters `"2017-06-15..2018-06-15"` for freshness, the response was a 500 error (Internal Server Error).

Although the official page shows the same usage for freshness of fifth:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference

... that doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question.

Comment: Do you have a question? This isn't the right place for bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, the parameter needs to look like this for some reason:

https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bin/v7.0/news/search?q=term&textFormat=HTML&freshness='2017-06-15..2018-06-16